# How can I resize an image in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm using reactnative with styled-components.

I want to upload an image. However, if I upload my image, the picture is cropped.

So, even if the image does not fit the original image size, I want to resize it so that the entire image is visible.

origin image

[image]

if i use my code image is cropped like this

[image]

this is my code

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components/native';
    import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';

    const Container = styled(ScrollView)`
      background: #013436;
      flex: 1;
    `;

    const MenuContainer = styled.View`

      padding: 0% 2%;
    `;

    const ImageStyle = styled.Image`
      width: 98%;
      height: 250px;
      border-radius: 28px;
      margin-left: 1.3%;
      margin-top: 1%;
    `;

    const MenuName = styled.View`
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 2%;
    `;

    const MenuLabel = styled.Text`
      font-size: 26px;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'BMHANNAPro';

    `;


    const DeRecipe = () => {

      return (
        <Container>
          <MenuContainer>
            <ImageStyle source={item.image} />
            <MenuName>
              <MenuLabel>{item.name} 만들기</MenuLabel>
            </MenuName>
          </MenuContainer>
        </Container>
      );
    };

    export default DeRecipe;
```

I want to resize the image so that it is 250px high and not cropped. So I want the whole image to be visible. How do I fix my code?

Comment: use: `resizeMode: 'contain'` for react-native: for styled components: `object-fit: contain`;

Answer (score 0):

To have images scaled responsively you must set width to be 100% so in your case it'd be:

```
const ImageStyle = styled.Image`
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 28px;
  margin-left: 1.3%;
  margin-top: 1%;
`;
```

Comment: if i use height:auto image disappear